# Error la aplicacion se detuvo

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-auth

Estoy desarrolando una app en Android Studio utilizando Kotlin, acabo de agregar implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.0' y la app sincroninza y compila sin problemas. Al probarla en mi telefono me da el error la aplicacion se detuvo. Anexo el codigo de build.gradle y manifest. Probe la app antes de instalar de descagar el archivo y funciono perfectamente ahora incluso borrando el archivo me da el mismo error. Espero me puedan ayudar gracias.

I am developing an app in Android Studio using Kotlin, I just added implementation 'com.google.firebase: firebase-analytics: 17.4.0' and the app syncs and compiles without problems. When testing it on my phone I get the error the application stopped. I attach the code of build.gradle and manifest. Try the app before installing to download the file and it works perfectly now even deleting the file gives me the same error. I hope you can help me, thanks.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.losdulcesdeandrea"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

MANIFEST

````
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.losdulcesdeandrea">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label=""
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AuthActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest> ```
````

Comment: Hola! Podrías agregar lo que el log muestra cuando la app se detiene, ahi podremos visualizar un mejor panorama de la situación.

Comment: Esto puede ser infinidad de causas "Error la aplicacion se detuvo", es super importante el  uso del LogCat, revisa que se registra ahí como error, saludos.

Comment: el logcat de Android Studio no me da ningun error

Comment: Hola @AlexanderHernandez , es imposible que no de ningun error si la aplicacion falla

Comment: intenta una instalación limpia. A veces funciona :). Y si tal vez puedas encontrar el error debugeando, podrías agregar breakpoints.